# Azure Communication Group calling hero sample Application, in this application is it possible to implement chat feature

Tags: azure, azure-communication-services

I Clone the azure communication-services-web-calling-hero public-preview branch code (Implemented React and . Net). In this application is it possible to implement a chat feature same as communication-services-web-chat-hero (Both are in one application). Please guide me

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not available yet. It's currently in beta, you may checkout the [UI library](https://github.com/Azure/communication-ui-library/) - We have a meeting example which incorporates both calling and chat features. You may look at this [Meeting samples](https://github.com/Azure/communication-ui-library/tree/main/samples/Meeting) for a test.

We have also relayed your feedback internally to our team. Apologies for any inconvenience! We appreciate your interest and feedback on this.